# Render markdown cells with pandoc in the ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pandoc

I know that it's possible add custom `css` and `js` to our ipython notebooks. I also know that we can change the templates used to convert a `ipynb` file to static html with `nbconvert`. However I didn't figure out how we can change templates. for rendering the live ipython notebook.

I'm using **ipython==2.20** installed via `pip` on a Ubuntu 14.04 distribution.

**I'd like to process all my markdown cells with `pandoc`** and not node.js `marked` as it is done by default in the `IPython/html/static/notebook/js/textcell.js`

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done out-of-the-box with IPython notebook, unfortunately.  The mathjax javascript library is available to the IPython notebook so Markdown can be parsed, but no such javascript library for using pandoc to render the text cell exists.

I would recommend investigating [commonmark](https://github.com/jgm/commonmark.js), [node-pdc](https://github.com/pvorb/node-pdc) and [markmon](https://github.com/yyjhao/markmon) for inspiration if you would like to investigate writing such a library.